# Transfer RAM from MacBook Mid 2010 to MacBook Pro 2008

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, memory

I ruined my beloved mid 2010 MacBook and planning to get a used MacBook Pro 2008 (not unibody) now. Currently, I have 2x4GB memory units in my MacBook and I would like to now if I can use at least one of them in the MacBook Pro. I heard that the 2008 Pro only supports up to 6 Gb, so I would like to use 1x4GB from my MacBook, and 1xGB from the Pro.

I am not fully sure if I want a 2008 Pro yet. These are some points that would influence my decision

Comment: MacBook Pro early 2008 or late 2008?

Comment: Oh, I don't know yet. I was just starting to look for used MacBook Pros 2008 in general. It sounds like that it would make a difference. By how far?

Comment: Early 2008 use DDR2 ram, late 2008 use DDR3 as your mid 2010 macbook

Comment: I was interested in a particular one, which seems to be in quite good condition and relatively cheap. It would be an early 2008 model. So let's say early 2008.

Comment: thanks. So in a late 2008 model 1066 Mhz DDR3 would work? And what about the hard disks?

Comment: Both use 2,5" Serial Ata, you can put directly your disk, but is better to do a fresh OS install

Comment: This is a great example of why we like one question per question. You can't accept the good answer you have since you asked a two part question. Let's get you to ask the storage question separately and see if both get good answers in isolation. Please head to our Meta site to ask why I'm removing your second question about SSD from this post. I've placed a lock on this to get your attention - please flag this if you need to make an edit before the lock period expires.

Comment: The late 2008 model supports up to 8 (officially only 6, but it can actually do 8) GB of 1066 Mhz DDR3.

Comment: What do you mean by "I ruined my beloved mid 2010 MacBook," why not try to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several MacBook Pro models [released in 2008](http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2008.html). Only the *Unibody* models support DDR3 RAM, so keep an eye out for those. Fortunately, they're easy to spot compared to the non-Unibody models released the same year.

Comment: I was planning to get the non-unibody. Sorry for the confusion, i did not know that the unibody was released in 2008 already

Comment: Would also be interested if someone tried to swap hard drives

Answer (score 1):

FREEWARE "**MacTracker**" gives *all* of the hardware information
that you could ever need, for every piece of Mac hardware ever sold.

See:  http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/5968/mactracker

Answer (score -1):

- MacBook Pro 2008: SO-DIMM PC3-8500 DDR3-1066 CL7
- MacBook Pro Mid-2010: SO-DIMM PC3-8500 DDR3-1066 CL7

Thus, you can freely put your sticks into the MacBook! :)

Comment: According to [this Apple doc](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP4?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), the Early and Late 2008 MacBooks Pro took DDR2 RAM. Do you have a source that says they support DDR3?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/sp499 — 2GB (two 1GB SO-DIMMs) or 4GB (two 2GB SO-DIMMs) of 1066MHz DDR3 SDRAM; two SO-DIMM slots support up to 4GB

Comment: Thats weird. In my mid 2010 i currently have 8GB (2 x4)DDR3 1066 Mhz, if the mac book pro from 2008 support the same RAM units why is it just 4Gb in sum then. I just read though, that apple locked it down to 6 gb for whatever reason

Comment: @kenansulayman first you say that i can switch freely, then you point out that 4 GB sticks are not supported, that's confusing

Comment: Hey. I'm not sure but I guess the MacBook Pro was 32bit back then. However, the hardware should support 64bit with Lion / Mountain Lion, thus support more than 6gb. I just tested it (MacBook Pro Late 2011 => MacBook Pro Late 2008) and it worked if I only had sticks of the same kind. (ML running on it)

Comment: Okay.. it confused me, too, that the unibody was already in production back then. Sorry. However, my answer fits to Unibodies in 2008.

Comment: @bluewoodtree depends on the motherboard chipset.

Comment: From what I read on various discussion boards, it should theoretically support up to 8 Gb, but there is some kind of software restriction by Apple that throttles it to 6 Gb